# Setting base url after building a Vite React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, vite

I have a Vite React app where I cannot set the base url beforehand. I use Azure to run the build pipeline and creating releases. But we have multiple environments and those environment names should come before path names. Like this:

```
{hostname}/{envName}/{appName}/{reactRouting}
```

So I only know `envName` after the building pipeline while creating a release for a specific environment. I can set `window.ENV_NAME` during release. Is there a way to set the base url using `window.ENV_NAME` but after the build?